# To display result on the same webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using php, mysql and ajax to display a contact form , but the problem is that the output "1 record inserted" gets showed on the next page . I want to be displayed on the same page on submit .

Following is the code

validation.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 //  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myButton").click(function() { 
    alert("Hii");
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'validation.php',
        data: $("#contact").serialize(),
        success: function(d) {
            $("#record").html(d);
        }
        });
    }); 
});

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" id="contact" action="validation.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="pass"> <br>
    Mobile: <input type="number" name="mobile"> <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="mybutton"/>
    </form>
    <div id="record">Record has been inserted</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please point out how i can go on doing so or what all changes are needed ?

Comment: Use ajax post again, instead of submit

Comment: Will have to look into it , initial search makes sense to your answer . Can u be a bit more descriptive and post it as an answer ?

Comment: Why don't you make the `<input type="submit"` into `<input type="button"` and `<form action="#"` ? Also your `mybutton` is different from `myButton`

Comment: Because validation.php consists of the mysql query , if i don't mention the action , it won't insert the data

Comment: Mentioning it in your `form` tag is redundant since the ajax function is going to `validation.php` . Is your alert being triggered?

Comment: nope , it isn't triggering too .

Comment: Did you change the `$("#myButton").click` to `$("#mybutton").click` ? It's case-sensitive.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46138/discussion-between-user007-and-kdp)

Comment: Made a silly mistake on my part by keeping 2 script tags open, it worked just fine after removing it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you click `#myButton`, you're submitting the form and it redirects you.

Simply prevent the default action.

```
$("#myButton").click(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault();
alert("Hii"); //what is this for???
    $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'validation.php',
    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
    success: function(d) {
        $("#record").html(d);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: I did the same , but it's still getting redirected to the next page :(

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on, if you prevent the default, the form shouldn't be submitted at all

Comment: I have inserted a echo in if else loop that shows the data has been in inserted in validation.php , there is nothing more to it .

Comment: Made a silly mistake on my part by keeping 2 script tags open, it worked just fine after removing it .

Comment: And yes dat alert("Hii") was for checking if the script is actually running or not :)

Answer (score 1):

U are submitting the button, Just change

```
<input type="button" id="myButton">Submit</input>
OR
<button id="myButton">Submit</button>
```

It will invoke your ajax request.

Comment: How was this upvoted? A button inside of a form will still default to a submit action.

Comment: doesn't makes sense to me too and checked it too just to be sure , it gets redirected .

Comment: Guys, if he'll use submit, the request will be goes as form submission and this would not invoke your JQuery event function. See the user's form, there is not use of onsubmit="return false;" so it will goes to the server directly using HTTP request

Comment: Made a silly mistake on my part by keeping 2 script tags open, it worked just fine after removing it .

Answer (score 0):

Currently the form is submitted by your button, because it is a `Submit-Button`. If you don't want the submission of the form there are several methods, but these two are the best:

```
// Use prevent default
$("#myButton").click(function(e) { // This 'e' is important
  e.preventDefault()
  # rest of the function here
});
```

or you could just replace your Submit button with a link tag (just with a placeholder href) like here:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Actual Javascript code here
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" id="contact" action="validation.php">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="pass"> <br>
    Mobile: <input type="number" name="mobile"> <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="mybutton">SUBMIT</a>
    </form>
    <div id="record">Record has been inserted</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Best case would be combining both.

Comment: It took you 8 minutes to post the answer I posted?

Comment: Read carefully, I suggested a different help!

Answer (score 0):

its open another page because your form will do submit procces when you click `#myButton`.
there are some way to solve this.
1. add attribute into your form tag:

```
<form method="post" id="contact" action="validation.php" onsubmit="return false;">
```

or
2. make your button to prevent submit procces by returning `false`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myButton").click(function() { 
        alert("Hii");
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'validation.php',
            data: $("#contact").serialize(),
            success: function(d) {
                $("#record").html(d);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Tried this , but the data doesn't gets inserted into the database

Comment: your `return false` is outside the callback function of `click`

Comment: sorry my fault, return should be in click function

Comment: did the change , but it still doesn't inserts into db .

Comment: did u correct the button id? make sure you have change it into same id (button id in the script and in the html)

Comment: Made a silly mistake on my part by keeping 2 script tags open, it worked just fine after removing it .

Answer (score 0):

try to call function `onclick` event of input element

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="mybutton" onclick="return myFunction()"/>
```

then call this function

```
function myFunction()
{
    $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'validation.php',
    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
    success: function(d) {
        $("#record").html(d);
    }
    });
  return false;
}
```

also replace this

```
<form method="post" id="contact" action="validation.php">
```

with

```
<form method="post" id="contact" action="validation.php" onsubmit="return false;">
```

It should help you!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <input type="button" id="myButton">Submit</input>
```

OR
   Submit